# cannot convert value to float in Apache Cassandra

Tags: python, database, cassandra, nosql

This the error I am getting, I have mentioned the code I am using for creating table in the first section. I know that csvreader gets the data in string format but type casting is just not working.

```
create_table1 = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS song_info_by_session (
        session_id int, 
        item_in_session int, 
        artist_name varchar,
        length float, 
        song text,  
        PRIMARY KEY(session_id, item_in_session))
"""

try:
    session.execute(create_table1)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

```
file = 'event_datafile_new.csv'

with open(file, encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)
    next(csvreader) # skip header
    for line in csvreader:
        insert_table1 = """INSERT INTO song_info_by_session  
                    (session_id, 
                    item_in_session,
                    artist_name, 
                    length, 
                    song) 
                """
        insert_table1 = insert_table1 + "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        session.execute(insert_table1, (int(line[8]), int(line[3]), line[0], float(line[5]), line[9]))
```

[image]

Comment: I'd double-check your table definition.  That error (to me) says that `length` is defined as a `TEXT` in Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd recommend using a prepared statement.  Prepared statements perform faster and they make it easier to get your columns and types correct.

To get this to work, I rearranged your code a little:

```
file = 'event_datafile_new.csv'

insert_table1 = """INSERT INTO song_info_by_session  
    (session_id, 
    item_in_session,
    artist_name, 
    length, 
    song) 
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
"""

pStatement = session.prepare(insert_table1);

with open(file, encoding = 'utf8') as f:
    csvreader = csv.reader(f)

    for line in csvreader:

        session.execute(pStatement,(int(line[0]),int(line[1]),line[2],float(line[3]),line[4]))
```

I then ran the script using my own `event_datafile_new.csv`, which looked like this:

```
101,912,Rush,20.33,2112
```

That worked, and I can `SELECT` that row via cqlsh:

```
> SELECT * FROM song_info_by_session WHERE session_id=101;

 session_id | item_in_session | artist_name | length | song
------------+-----------------+-------------+--------+------
        101 |             912 |        Rush |  20.33 | 2112

(1 rows)
```

Pro tip:  I recommend *not* running `CREATE` and other DDL statements from inside of application code.  If you search on this site for problems with schema disagreement in Cassandra, you'll almost always find that whoever was having that problem was also creating their table from code.  Creating your tables manually or in batch via cqlsh is the "happy path."